# Develop the Taylor series of $\ln(z^2-5z+6)$ in $z=0$

Tags: complex-analysis, taylor-expansion

Also, determine the radius of convergence. $\ln$ is the principal branch of the complex logarithm.

What I've tried is splitting the function into $\ln(z-3)+\ln(z-2)$ and then finding the formula for $f^{(n)}(0)$ and plugging that in the Taylor series.

What I get (assuming I didn't make a mistake) is $f(z)=\ln(-3)+\ln(-2)-\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{\frac{1}{3^n}+\frac{1}{2^n}}{n\color{red}!}z^n$

When I plug that into WolframAlpha, it calculates that the sum converges to a function that doesn't match mine in almost any value.

I'm guessing the mistake is ignoring the domain of $\ln$, or maybe using a property that doesn't hold for complex logarithms.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: the $x^n$ term in the expansion of $\log(1-x)$ has denominator $n$ not $n!$

Comment: @DavidHolden This doesn't tell me what mistake I made since I didn't use the known expansion for $\log$

Comment: @DavidHolden Oh. I did manage to find it.

Comment: If you have found out the problem, Luka, let me encourage you to write up what you found, and to post it as an answer.